# PHP format multiple entries from textarea regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I can get the number from a file using Regex and PHP for example:

```
<?PHP
  $txt='house.1x01.pilot.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4';
  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/.*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)/is", $txt, $matches))
  {
      $int1=$matches[1][0];
      $int2=$matches[2][0];
      print "($int1) ($int2) \n";
  }
?>
```

but what i want to do is for instance, enter multiple file names in a text área and convert this:

```
house.1x02.paternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4
house.1x03.occams_razor.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4
house.s04e15.dvdrip.xvid-orpheus.mp4
```

into this

```
INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '1', '2', 'house.1x02.paternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4');

INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '1', '3', 'house.1x03.occams_razor.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4');

INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '4', '15', 'house.s04e15.dvdrip.xvid-orpheus.mp4');
```

Format it for SQL, removing the 0 just keeping the 1 2 3, etc. and not 01 02 03 make it easier to copy-paste the query and insert into the database. As there is so many file names, kind of time-consuming doing it one by one.

is there any better way to acquire this?

Comment: Apparently, the only unknown thing is getting these 1x0`2` 1x0`3`  s04e`15`. Why not just say this is what you're trying to match. It can't be matched without strict rules of it's location in the string and the variable format that represents it. Why people are trying to answer this is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be easy to do something like this:

```
// YOUR ARRAY WITH FILE NAMES
$files = array('house.1x02.paternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4',
               'house.1x03.occams_razor.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4',
               'house.s04e15.dvdrip.xvid-orpheus.mp4'
              );

$show = 18; // THE SHOW ID TO INSERT

$sql = array(); // EMPTY ARRAY TO HOLD THE QUERIES

// CREATE A CONNECTION TO YOUR DATABASE: 
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "databasename");

// LOOP THROUGH FILES...        
foreach($files as $txt){

  if ($c=preg_match_all ("/.*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)/is", $txt, $matches)) {
      $season = intval($matches[1][0]); // REMOVES ANY LEADING ZEROS..
      $episode = intval($matches[2][0]); // REMOVES ANY LEADING ZEROS.

      // RUN YOUR QUERY HERE:
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '".$show."', '". $season ."', '". $episode ."', '". $txt ."')";
      $con->query($sql);
      // OR UNCOMMENT TO SAVE IN ARRAY FOR LATER USE IF YOU WANT:
      //$sql[] = "INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '".$show."', '". $season ."', '". $episode ."', '". $txt ."')";  
  }

}
```

Would build SQL-queries like you requested:

```
INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '1', '2', 'house.1x02.paternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4');
INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '1', '3', 'house.1x03.occams_razor.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4');
INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '4', '15', 'house.s04e15.dvdrip.xvid-orpheus.mp4');
```

**DEMO:**
SQL: http://rextester.com/HHG48901
PHP: http://rextester.com/ZSMJ67483

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I wanted, perhaps not the most pretty way of doing it, but it worked.

```
<?php 
$eps = array("house.1x02.paternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x03.occams_razor.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x04.maternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x05.damned_if_you_do.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x06.the_socratic_method.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x07.fidelity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x08.poison.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x09.dnr.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x10.histories.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x11.detox.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x12.sports_medicine.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x13.cursed.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x14.control.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x15.mob_rules.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x16.heavy.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x17.role_model.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x18.babies_and_bathwater.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x19.kids.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x20.love_hurts.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x21.three_stories.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4","house.1x22.honeymoon.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4"); 

foreach ($eps as $value) {
    if ($c=preg_match_all ("/.*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)/is", $value, $matches)) {
        $int1=$matches[1][0];
        $int2=$matches[2][0];
        $array2=array('10','20','30');
        if (!in_array($int1,$array2)) {
            $int1=str_replace("0","",$int1);
        }
        if (!in_array($int2,$array2)) {
            $int2=str_replace("0","",$int2);
        }

        echo "INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '$int1', '$int2', '$value'); <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

I added that array so it would not remove the 0 from 10 or 20. is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just use `intval()` to get the number as an integer.. dont need any replace. Se my Answer..

Comment: You are welcome, hope it works out for you

Comment: @MichaelK i tried to execute the query directly on the file which u recommended $con->query($sq); but i am getting this error
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

Comment: oddd, it actually runs the query but im getting these errors. 

INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '1', '2', 'house.1x02.paternity.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4');Error: Array
INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '1', '3', 'house.1x03.occams_razor.ws_dvdrip_xvid-fov.mp4');Error: Array
INSERT INTO `tvshow` (`id`, `show_id`, `season`, `episode`, `file`) VALUES (NULL, '18', '4', '15', 'house.s04e15.dvdrip.xvid-orpheus.mp4');Error: Array

Comment: You must first create a connection to the database you want to insert into. Have you done that? I would help if you could update your question with the database table schema, and the data types for each column, do you store the numbers as integers etc..

Comment: Updated with database insert example and demos on rextester: SQL: http://rextester.com/HHG48901 PHP: http://rextester.com/ZSMJ67483

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/.*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)/is"  -- working too hard; instead:

"/(\d+).(\d+)/"
```

- Since regexp is not anchored, there is no need for leading `.*?`
- `.*? is the same as`.*`
- I don't think you need the extra backslashes.
- The separator between the numbers is strange.  I cannot really be zero-length, else the `\d+` would have pick up the second string of digits.
- `/i` is unnecessary since there are no letters.
- Avoiding leading zeros seems unnecessary; MySQL will treat the *string*  `'010'` as ten, not eight.  (I suspect you were concerned that *PHP* would treate `010` as eight.)
- The `/s` is probably unnecessary -- will there be multiple "lines"?